# Duplicate management: Insert Account Id of duplicate record in API REST Response

Tags: rest-api, api, account, duplicate-management, person-accounts

I'm planning to integrate an external website with Salesforce.
In Salesforce I used Matching and Duplicate rules in order to block the creation of new duplicated PersonAccount and those rules work like a sharm.

1. Add One Person Account

This External website will insert new PersonAccounts using API REST.
I'm testing this scenario using the workbench, and when SF find a duplicates it returns something like this:

[image: Workbench results]

How can I add the AccountId of the duplicate record in the response?

2. Bulk API - Load data from an old database full of Accounts

In this scenario I need to send old data in SF using bulk API.

- How  the duplicate management will be managed using Bulk API?
- in a standard way, can SF returns the Id of duplicates records?

**Update**

In order to accomplish question number 1, you can follow this question:

*Salesforce Rest API create account* and follow steps in the accepted response:[Salesforce Rest API create account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247648/salesforce-rest-api-create-account?rq=1)

Comment: AFAIK, this is a standard salesforce responce and you can not modify this.

Comment: ok, how can I use in order to reach my goal?

Comment: You will need to write a custom web service.. However, I suggest you wait for some time and see if there is any easy solution to your problem.

Comment: You can use SOAP API's [`DuplicateRuleHeader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_duplicateruleheader.htm) here. There's [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEL5QAM) to allow similar feature with REST API, but none exists today.